# Why am I being told "Wait some of your questions have not been well recived"?

Tags: support, user-accounts, chat, privileges

I have asked three questions, but am now seeing a "Wait some of your questions have not been well received" banner across my profile. What can I do to improve my questions?

At first I didn't know how to add links or images to my questions. I did by the time I was done asking my first question.

I've spent more than nine hours writing up my three questions so far, jumping around the Internet finding links and researching sites, looking for what I thought was the kind of info a Super User question should include. I've checked every word for errors with proofreading and editing. Only then to watch them remain unanswered or told "they weren't researched" and hacked down, then chopped up and now I'm told they weren't valid or "well received".

On [my first question](https://superuser.com/questions/949735/what-is-this-mix-of-chinese-arabic-korean-japanese-user-owning-a-process-listeni) I thought I did a pretty good job for never having used this site.

I am trying my best to ask them in the way that will be not only positively received but useful to others. I am also trying to follow "guidelines" that are not really clearly explained to a new user.

I don't understand why I am being told that I won't be able to ask any more questions when the three I have asked were never even given much consideration, and only scrutinized for grammatical errors. They are still unanswered.

They get downvoted with no reason given and make me feel stupid because after hours of trying to solve my issue I had to come here without posting the answer in the form of a question.

Is it that I didn't make my questions good enough to suit the taste of every one of the tens of thousands of other users on this site who may or may not choose to read them?

Whatever it may be I have not given up on this site even though I am frustrated and often feel like just giving up and going somewhere else to find my answer.

Is there anyone here with a bit more time and experience who wouldn't mind taking some time to help me with a few of the finer points of Super User (like how to open the private chat dialog) so I don't get any of my privileges suspended?

I am a father of six with two in diapers so I find it hard to be completely focused on the computer and quite often have to step away to deal with more "pressing and stinkier issues" so I bounce back and forth when I'm on here.

I would like to continue using this site and become a helpful and contributing member but honestly, I am sitting here looking at the screen afraid that if I post this question it will first be edited, then downvoted, and in the end it will remain unanswered and I will no longer be able to ask questions.

Comment: @JoeBrown - Voting is anonymous for a reason.  There is no possible way to who issued the downvote.  So being snarky about a downvote isn't constructive.  Reputation on the origin site ( i..e Superuser ) is adjusted once a question is migrated ( i.e. meta.superuser )

Comment: Look man I can take a hint I'll delete my account with Superuser and find answers to my somewhere else. Sorry for wasting your time . Ramhound You have been more then helpful in answering this and made your point quite clear that I am not welcome wanted and should just leave.

Comment: The chats are located here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=superuser.com but require 20 reputation.

Comment: Can't say pity votes didn't just rain

Comment: @JoeBrown - I made exactly one comment towards an actual question that you asked, and a comment to this question, when it was at its original location.

Comment: MC10 Thank you for you answer to my question bud.

Comment: Anonymous voting is a good and a bad thing. I see both sides. The issue though appears you're taking downvotes personally. That is NOT (IMO) what they are intended for. Votes are a way of saying "this question has problems" or "this question is great", that's all. I've been voted and been annoyed at it. But instead, try to find out why, and edit and correct. Your posts in general are very long, usually (not always) making questions appear too broad or too confusing (unclear). Ensure posts are as focused as can be. I actually ignore the voting system personally and use it only for rudeness or

Comment: lack of research effort. Other than that, I don't downvote. However, I'm actually (arguably) using the voting system incorrectly. Also, Ramhound is right with what he is saying, don't get awkward towards him, whilst his comments can be read as short, you'll find the site encourages that ethos (short, clear, to the point). This typcially comes across as emotionless or snappy, but, if you actually read his comments you'll realise it's meaningful and can help (if you chose to accept it). So don't be annoyed, personally I'd delete the questions with -1 or -2 and re-write, making it more focused :)

Comment: @Dave - Removing his questions will still count against his ability to ask new questions though, and with his questions deleted, I recall reading deleted questions will count multiple times in the equation that determines the quality of his submissions.  It is very likely the removal of these questions will just end up resulting in inability to ask questions.